# what are the sampling methods in spark? Why not reservoir sampling?

Tags: apache-spark, sampling

I know reservoir sampling can be applied in parallel, but spark seems use the other sampling methods I have no idea about. could someone describe them briefly?

According to @Tristan answer, I guess the purpose of not using reservoir sampling is to keep the balance of classes. But I go though the source code and found noting about labels.

Answer (score -1):

I know the existence of [Stratified sampling](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-statistics.html#stratified-sampling)

Comment: You may also check out this link : https://databricks.com/blog/2014/08/27/statistics-functionality-in-spark.html